# Using functions in RPD in OBIEE

Tags: function, variables, prompt, obiee

Need help..I have a column prompt in the dashboard..I want to use the value selected from the drop down to act as a parameter for function that i have specified for a column in the RPD.

My task is to make sure that when I select 'USD' in the column prompt, the column (for which i gave the function) should convert accordingly considering the selection 'USD' as a parameter for the function.

If I add the function in the column formula in the front end, I am able to see the amount getting converted. Now I need to use the same thing in he back end instead of using it in the front end because clients aren't aware of how to add the function for each and every column that they want to convert.

My function has 4 (amount,old currency,new currency and date) parameters..

I hope i am clear. Pls share your expert knowledge.

Comment: Can you please add the front end function you are currently using as an example? Also do you have a table that stores exchange rates at the appropriate grain that you could simply join to and use a formula on the LTS (Logical Table Source) to get?

Comment: Function is like 

get_currency(%1,%2,%3,%4) where 
1= amount to be converted, 
2= current currency(USD or Eur or etc which I use from the column), 
3= new currency(which i select from the dashboard prompt, 
4= the date(to check the current value).   And yes we do have a table that stores the latest converaion rates, but haven't imported to the rpd...

Comment: Would importing that exchange rate table into the RPD and building out the calculations there be possible for your situation? Performance would be a bit better, the only downside is that you must remember to select a currency code or else you data will be multiplied by the number of distinct currency codes you are storing...

Comment: But how do we handle the part where we are looking for a currency value that the user has selected from prompt in dashboard..."%3" part in my function

Comment: If you use a table, you will not need to have the value passed down to you because it will be based on an is prompted filter. The user would simply select a value from a column prompt you would create, and that prompt would pass the value down to the filter in the associated report. I will take some time here later on and submit an answer with some images of how ours is set up that may be more clear. Hopefully I am fully understanding what you are asking!

Comment: Thanks Mark P, I will wait for ur reply...meanwhile let me try importing the table and convert the values...